# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Tags: python, typeerror

i have an error in second line of the function   `stream.write(self._header + b_("\n"))` where it throws the exception .I am not able to debug the problem by so far, I am using python 3.(signpdf) It is an old python package which downloaded but while running it seems it is designed to work on python 2.

```
object_positions = []
        stream.write(self._header + b_("\n"))
        for i in range(len(self._objects)):
            idnum = (i + 1)
            obj = self._objects[i]
            object_positions.append(stream.tell())
            stream.write(b_(str(idnum) + " 0 obj\n"))
            key = None
            if hasattr(self, "_encrypt") and idnum != self._encrypt.idnum:
                pack1 = struct.pack("<i", i + 1)[:3]
                pack2 = struct.pack("<i", 0)[:2]
                key = self._encrypt_key + pack1 + pack2
                assert len(key) == (len(self._encrypt_key) + 5)
                md5_hash = md5(key).digest()
                key = md5_hash[:min(16, len(self._encrypt_key) + 5)]
            obj.writeToStream(stream, key)
            stream.write(b_("\nendobj\n"))
```

Comment: It's likely the original stream was opened as text (for example, `open(filename, 'w')` or `open(filename, 'wt')`).  In this case, writing bytes is forbidden.  If it's meant to be binary, make sure the original stream is opened as binary (`open(filename, 'wb')`).

Answer (score 1):

You should check how your stream is opened. I think defaults has changed between python 2 and 3.